# Power BI Admin connection string allows only 500 chars?

Tags: business-intelligence, office365, office365-apps, powerbi

I've been scouring the blogs and MS docs to no avail.

I'm trying to set up scheduled data refresh but the connection string (OleDb) from Excel is 1906 chars long and the Power BI Admin connection string text box only allows 500 chars.

Is this a Power BI problem or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a limitation in current Power BI design.

1) Would you mind sharing the connection string with us to review for future improvement?
2) Meanwhile have you tried setup using option with connection properties instead of connection string?

Best Regards.